# How do I stop Gmail from opening mailto links in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, email, thunderbird, gmail, mailto

I followed the instructions to set Gmail as my default email client by inserting this:

> In address bar of same tab, type/paste this & hit enter:

```
javascript:navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto", "https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s", "Gmail");
```

How do I change this to Thunderbird?  I don't want Gmail to open mailto links in Chrome.

Comment: What operating system is being used?

Answer (score 4):

The mailto function opens the primary email client. If you want to use Gmail as your client there is no way to open mailto in Thunderbird.

If you want to move from Gmail to Thunderbird you should try to set it through the Thunderbird preferences. There should be a button like 'check if Thunderbird is default email client'.
As an alternative follow Ali's description.

Answer (score 2):

1. Launch the default Mac OS X email application (called "Mail", located in the /Applications folder.)
2. Select `Mail | Preferences` from the menu.
3. On the `General` tab, select "Thunderbird" from the Default email reader drop-down list.
4. Close Mail.

[image: Screenshot showing the settings]

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Chrome browser settings, then scroll down to "Show advanced settings". Look for "Privacy" and then click on "Content Settings". Scroll down to "Handlers" and click on "Manage handlers". You will see your "mailto" handler there and you can deselect Gmail. Hope this helps!