# Make Chrome open Apple Mail for email links?

Tags: google-chrome, apple-mail

When clicking email links in Chrome the default was for Mac Mail to be opened. I accidentally made gmail the default, and when I remove this email links don't open at all.

So much for "don't be evil" Chrome have made it not obvious how to undo this change.

Comment: See [Ali's answer](https://superuser.com/a/718175/1185802). It has to do with your Apple Mail settings.

Answer (score 3):

So I did follow @robodome2's answer, but there may also be a situation where Chrome has set Gmail or another email app as a default client via use of a "handler".

This Chrome "handler" seems to override certain options, like selecting Apple Mail as the default client within Apple Mail app's options, as it is wholly within Chrome's settings.

I simply had to right-click and there was an option asking me how to "open email link as..." and then it took me to the "handler" page. I simply removed Gmail (and Outlook was on there?) and viola... Apple's Mail app is now the default.

I suspect if you go the the "handler" options within Chrome you can manually change/delete.

Handlers can be found:

Settings --> Privacy and Security --> Site Settings --> In the "Permissions" section you'll find "Handlers"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this for my computer. The most important setting is not in Chrome but in Apple Mail!

In Apple Mail, set Apple Mail as the default email reader:

- open Apple Mail and select Preferences from the Mail menu
- on the General tab, find Default email reader and click on the drop-down menu
- click Select...
- in the "Applications" list, click Apple Mail
- click the Select button
- close the Preferences window

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome.  Go to Preferences/Settings.  Then Privacy and Security settings.  Scroll down to Default Browser.  Change this to Chrome.  Your computer settings will automatically update and every time you open a link in your mail your new browser default of Chrome should open.